# How to add libgdx as a sub view in android

Tags: android, libgdx

I have main.xml as follows:

```
  <RelativeLayout>
     ...
     <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/panel_sheet"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.libgdx.Sheet3DViewGdx 
                android:id="@+id/m3D"
                android:layout_width="1000dp"
                android:layout_height="600dp"
        />

    </FrameLayout>

...
</RelativeLayout>
```

And my main activity class is as follows:

```
public class Test extends Activity {

    MainActivity  m3DActivity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

My GDX class is as follows which extend ApplicationListener class rather than View.

```
public class Sheet3DViewGdx implements ApplicationListener{

    @Override
    public void create() {
        InputStream in = Gdx.files.internal("data/obj/Human3DModel.obj").read();
        model =  ObjLoader.loadObj(in);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }


    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        model.render(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES);
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int arg0, int arg1) {
        float aspectRatio = (float) arg0 / (float) arg1;
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }
}
```

Now, how should I add Sheet3DViewGdx as a subview in my main layout?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The AndroidApplication class (which extends activity) has a method named `initializeForView(ApplicationListener, AndroidApplicationConfiguration)` that will return a `View` you can add to your layout.

So your Test-class can extend AndroidApplication instead of Activity so that you can call that method and add the View to your layout.

If that's not an option, for some reason, take a look at what [AndroidApplication source code](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-android/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidApplication.java#L223) does, and mimic that.

Comment: Thanks @Matsemann. but still it doesn't explains how to acheive it. Can you please tell it briefly?

Answer (score 15):

I have created a [Hello World program on github](https://github.com/kbigdelysh/libgdx-in-fragment) for libgdx running in a fragment using Android Studio 2.1. It follows [the instructions on the official libgdx wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Starter-classes-%26-configuration#fragment-based-libgdx).

[image]

AndroidLauncher class:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFragmentApplication;

public class AndroidLauncher extends FragmentActivity implements  AndroidFragmentApplication.Callbacks {
    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.layout);

        // Create libgdx fragment
        GameFragment libgdxFragment = new GameFragment();

        // Put it inside the framelayout (which is defined in the layout.xml file).
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
                add(R.id.content_framelayout, libgdxFragment).
                commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void exit() {

    }


}
```

The GameFragment class:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidFragmentApplication;

public class GameFragment extends AndroidFragmentApplication{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // return the GLSurfaceView on which libgdx is drawing game stuff
        return initializeForView(new MyGdxGame());
    }
}
```

layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_framelayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2">
    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:textColor="#00FF00"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:text="I'm just a TextView here with red background :("/>

</LinearLayout>
```

MyGdxGame class:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture img;
    private BitmapFont font;


    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        img = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
        font = new BitmapFont();
        font.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        batch.begin();

        //batch.draw(img, 0, 0);
        font.getData().setScale(6.0f);
        font.draw(batch, "Hello World from libgdx running in a fragment! :)", 100, 300);

        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        batch.dispose();
        img.dispose();
    }
}
```

Make sure you've added the following:

```
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1"
```

To the project gradle script in the "dependencies {.}" section inside project (":android") section.

Answer (score 9):

Using a libgdx project as a view inside an Android app is now documented clearly, with example code, in the [libgdx wiki, implemented as a Fragment](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Starter-classes-and-configuration#fragment-based-libgdx) (the best practice for modern Android apps):

> 1. Add Android V4 Support Library to the -android project and its build path if you haven't already added it. This is needed in order to Extend FragmentActivity later
> 2. Change AndroidLauncher activity to extend FragmentActivity, not AndroidApplication
> 3. Implement AndroidFragmentApplication.Callbacks on the AndroidLauncher activity
> 4. Create a Class that extends AndroidFragmentApplication which is the Fragment implementation for Libgdx.
> 5. Add the initializeForView() code in the Fragment's onCreateView method.
> 6. Finally, replace the AndroidLauncher activity content with the Libgdx Fragment.

Comment: I have created a Hello Word program for libgdx running in a fragment using Android Studio 2.1 --> https://github.com/kbigdelysh/libgdx-in-fragment/archive/master.zip

Comment: I wish posting SO questions and answers included automatic links to Github projects for example code.

Comment: Here is an updated link or anyone looking for the FragmentActivity documentation: https://libgdx.com/wiki/app/starter-classes-and-configuration

Answer (score 6):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    cfg.useGL20 = false;
    //initialize(new LoveHearts(), cfg);
    LinearLayout lg=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.game);
    lg.addView(initializeForView(new LoveHearts(), cfg));
}
```

Comment: Easy and fast method.