# Building libgdx as a view inside a ViewController

Tags: ios, libgdx

Is there any way to build a libgdx application as a view/viewcontroller inside a main ViewController the [same way it can be done in Android with Views inside an Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894601/how-to-add-libgdx-as-a-sub-view-in-android)?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm looking at it too, taking this example and trying to change it https://upandcrawling.wordpress.com/2016/01/02/libgdx-and-google-mobile-ads-robopods-integration-ios/

Comment: I believe the change was introduced into the library a way ago. Tweet to badlogicgames and ask.

Comment: @MLProgrammer-CiM did you get an answer from badlogicgames?

Comment: I'd recommend you ping the github project.

Comment: @MLProgrammer-CiM so, did you find the solution ?