# Importing LibGDX to already existing project

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, libgdx

I am developing a multiplayer game with my team using LibGDX, but i dont know how can i get LibGDX files into my already existing project, that i started in gitlab. Can someone help please?

Oh and im using IntelliJ as my IDE

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add libgdx to existing project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30839796/how-to-add-libgdx-to-existing-project)

Comment: Thanks to your question I thought this may have been asked before, found an old question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30839796/6250401) and I hope my answer is useful to you.