# I want to have a minigame inside my notetaking application in android

Tags: android, kotlin, libgdx, libktx

I want to have a minigame inside my note-taking application.
(Eg: an activity with a chrome dinosaur clone.)

I have worked with libktx and libgdx before.
My question is can these libraries be used to work with normal android projects and can they be used to interoperate between a normal activity and the game activity?

So in essence i want to jump from my normal activity which takes notes to an activity which will have a minigame inside ..

Answer (score 1):

LibGDX can be embedded in an Android application as a [`Fragment`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) rather than a complete activity.

From [the official documentation](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Starter-classes-and-configuration#game-fragment):

> A libGDX game can be hosted in an Android Fragment instead of using a complete Activity. This allows it to take up a portion of the screen in an Activity or be moved between layouts. To create a libGDX fragment, subclass `AndroidFragmentApplication` and implement the `onCreateView()` with the following initialization:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return initializeForView(new MyGdxGame());
}
```

> That code depends on some other changes to the `-android` project:
>
> 1. [Add AndroidX Fragment Library to the -android project and its build path](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment) if you haven't already added it. This is needed in order to extend `FragmentActivity` later.
> 2. Change the `AndroidLauncher` Activity to extend `FragmentActivity`, not `AndroidApplication`.
> 3. Implement `AndroidFragmentApplication.Callbacks` on the `AndroidLauncher` Activity.
> 4. Create a class that extends `AndroidFragmentApplication` which is the `Fragment` implementation for libGDX.
> 5. Add the `initializeForView()` code in the `Fragment`'s `onCreateView` method.
> 6. Finally, replace the `AndroidLauncher` activity content with the libGDX `Fragment`.

For more examples, see [the official documentation](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Starter-classes-and-configuration#game-fragment) or [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894601/how-to-add-libgdx-as-a-sub-view-in-android).

LibKTX should work seamlessly in a `Fragment`, and you should be able to easily translate the examples from Java into Kotlin if you want to.

Comment: I will definitely try this and let you know . Thank you .